# No actualiza el idioma prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7

al hacer el cambio de idioma no actualiza correctamente el idioma de español a inglés y viceversa. Muchas veces para lograrlo tengo que cargar la web varias veces para que lo coja.  La versión específica de prestashop es 1.7.5.1. Se os ocurre alguna idea de porque puede estar pasando esto?, gracias.

Comment: que version de PHP estas usando? Al presionar el boton de idiomas te muestra algun error la consola de comandos? Puedes publicar que tipo de palabras o secciones no te estan cargando correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

puedes borrar el cache de smarty desde el backend de presta. Algunos cambios demoran su impacto por ese tema.
Puedes probar desde otro navegador tambien.

Comment: Lo he hecho y no lo soluciona, se os ocurre otra cosa?, algún bug o algo que pueda hacer que no cambie la traducción o que afecte a ella?

Comment: Ok, el tema es que elegis el idioma, desplegas el menu y elegis supongamos ingles. Una vez elegido tarda en verse? o tienes q darle click varias veces al boton para q lo tome? si el idioma esta elegido y le das f5 para refrescar el navegador en algun refresco de pagina lo trae el idioma. Si es algo asi hay un problema en las peticiones ajax. Podrias regenerar el htacces o fijarte de quitar las url amigables como para descartar algo de eso.

Comment: Sí. al cambiar de idioma , cambia perfectamente la url con su " www.tienda/en/categoria" , pero en cambio en la web no se actualizan las palabras traducidas. En cambio si refresco de nuevo incluso a veces hasta dos veces , coge la traducción. Es muy raro